# How to merge two dfs duplicating values in one of them to match the index

Tags: python, dataframe, merge

I have a large dataset (df1) from an experiment with different variables (n2o, doc, wfps and more) measured in a given date and corresponding to a treatment and a replicate of this treatment:

```
          date treatment  replicate  ...        nh4         doc       wfps
0   2021-03-01       RB1          1  ...  19.087379  136.846375  96.902478
1   2021-03-01       RB1          2  ...  31.037651  208.405320  96.902478
2   2021-03-01       RB1          3  ...  26.209304  206.291424  96.902478
3   2021-03-01       RB2          1  ...   8.328661   66.603010  48.121912
4   2021-03-01       RB2          2  ...   7.553159   50.175588  48.121912
..         ...       ...        ...  ...        ...         ...        ...
```

Every treatment has 3 replicates and we have 6 treatments, in total 18 values per date entry.

I want to merge a new df (df2), temperature data that needs to be repeated because it is constant for treatment and replicate but not date:

```
          date treatment  replicate  tsoil

0   2021-01-03       RB1        NaN   10.785484
1   2021-01-03       RB2        NaN   10.785484
2   2021-01-03       RB3        NaN   10.785484
3   2021-01-03       RT1        NaN   10.785484
4   2021-01-03       RT2        NaN   10.785484
..         ...       ...        ...         ...
145 2023-01-03       RB2        NaN   11.148387
146 2023-01-03       RB3        NaN   11.148387
147 2023-01-03       RT1        NaN   11.148387
148 2023-01-03       RT2        NaN   11.148387
149 2023-01-03       RT3        NaN   11.148387`
```

This dataset initialy contains the treatment column but I need the replicates (I added an empty 'replicate' column) to be able to merge with the main dataset. How can I fill a replicate column with repeated values for each date entry?

I tried merging both on date and treatment
`temp = pd.merge(df1,df2, on=['date', 'treatment], how='left')`
but I got a df with the length and columns from df1 and an extra column from df2 with empty values because it does not match the columns.

```
          date treatment  replicate_x  ...       wfps  replicate_y       tsoil

0   2021-03-01       RB1            1  ...  96.902478          NaN         NaN
1   2021-03-01       RB1            2  ...  96.902478          NaN         NaN
2   2021-03-01       RB1            3  ...  96.902478          NaN         NaN
3   2021-03-01       RB2            1  ...  48.121912          NaN         NaN
4   2021-03-01       RB2            2  ...  48.121912          NaN         NaN
..         ...       ...          ...  ...        ...          ...         ...
373 2023-03-01       RT2            2  ...  53.505246          NaN         NaN
374 2023-03-01       RT2            3  ...  53.505246          NaN         NaN
375 2023-03-01       RT3            1  ...  23.063324          NaN         NaN
376 2023-03-01       RT3            2  ...  23.063324          NaN         NaN
377 2023-03-01       RT3            3  ...  23.063324          NaN         NaN
```

desired result:

````
          date treatment  replicate_x  ...       wfps       tsoil
0   2021-03-01       RB1            1  ...  96.902478   10.785484
1   2021-03-01       RB1            2  ...  96.902478   10.785484
2   2021-03-01       RB1            3  ...  96.902478   10.785484
3   2021-03-01       RB2            1  ...  48.121912   10.785484
4   2021-03-01       RB2            2  ...  48.121912   10.785484
..         ...       ...          ...  ...        ...   ...
373 2023-03-01       RT2            2  ...  53.505246   11.148387
374 2023-03-01       RT2            3  ...  53.505246   11.148387
375 2023-03-01       RT3            1  ...  23.063324   11.148387
376 2023-03-01       RT3            2  ...  23.063324   11.148387
377 2023-03-01       RT3            3  ...  23.063324   11.148387
```
````

I thought of two options: merging the two dfs directly using the three columns as index (I do not know how to make it) or filling the empty tsoil column in the final df matching the three columns (maybe easier).